# constructor defined without parameter but still accepts a parameter

Tags: c#, constructor, attributes

I have a class calling the attribute below (`RequireTransaction`) which accepts a parameter but within the class definition, the constructor is defined without any parameters. How is this attribute constructor able to accept a parameter when there is no constructor defined with one?

```
[RequiresTransaction(IncludeData = true)]
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
  return something;
};


public class RequiresTransactionAttribute
{
    public bool IncludeData { get; set; }

    public RequiresTransactionAttribute()
    {
        IncludeData = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The attribute syntax is not a constructor call syntax...

Comment: could you please explain further?

Comment: You have made an assumption that there is a constructor involved. There isn't, even though it kind of looks like there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/):

> Named or optional parameters correspond to either properties or fields of the attribute.

The named parameter here corresponds to the `IncludeData` property, and since it's a named parameter, it does not require a corresponding constructor argument.

Answer (score 2):

This is called [named parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#positional-and-named-parameters)

> Each non-static public read-write field and property for an attribute class defines a named parameter for the attribute class.